# Windows 8 Freezing in bootcamp

Tags: windows-8, freeze, boot-camp

I am running windows 8.1 in bootcamp on an iMAC.  It worked fine for a few days, but now it freezes no matter what is running.  Visual Studio freezes after 10 - 15 lines of code, IE freezes after one url is entered, Windows update will not go etc.  The only thing that seems to work is even while it is frozen I can go into windows explorer and I can go into task manager to kill IE etc.  I have tried updating BootCamp drivers with no luck.  Any ideas what to try.  I am 99% sure it is not a virus, because the machine has virus protection and it also has never been used for anything other than development.  The only web sites that have ever been browsed to are developer related.

Thanks
Jimmy